# Controls Inspector Below Identity Inspector Missing in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, user-controls, interface-builder, xcode10

I recently updated my Xcode 9 to Xcode 10.1.  At the right bottom of the inspector pane for storyboard, the searchbox that always used to be there for finding controls such as `ViewController`, `UIImageView`, `UITextfield` etc. and dragging them to the storyboard is missing. I can't find it anywhere in the menu structure.

Does anyone know how to get it to display?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes top right, left to the `Show Standard Editor` button.
you can access it with `shift + cmd + L` too.

[image: Library button]

Don't forget to select a xib or storyboard file first.

And it name is `Library` by the way.

Comment: Thx.  I got it to appear as a popup.  Is there a way to get it to appear at bottom right as it does in xcode 9?

Comment: Unfortunately not! but if you hold option key while you open it, it will sticks open until you explicitly close it.